# Issue in converting date format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have assigned the value of date to a dictionary like so...

```
userDetailsDictionary["birth_date"] = "\(birthDateVar)"
```

Now this gives the date in `dd-mm-yyyy`. But I want the date in `yyyy-mm-dd`. For that I tried something like this...

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
let bday = dateFormatter.date(from: birthDateVar)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let bdayString = dateFormatter.string(from: bday!)
```

Though `birthDateVar` has the value in it, while I'm trying to convert it, it is showing as nil and so `bday` is becoming nil. Confused as to what the reason is...

Comment: show the `birthDateVar`

Comment: `birthDateVar ` gives something like `28-08-2017`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your date format from

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
```

to

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

**Updated answer**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
let bday = dateFormatter.date(from: birthDateVar)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let bdayString = dateFormatter.string(from: bday!)
```

Comment: Thanks @Three Coins..Such a silly mistake..didn't notice I was giving month instead of date!..But thanks anyways...:)

Comment: @User.bw - sometimes happens this scenario , but your ? has answer `Now this gives the date in dd-mm-yyyy`